# Print the result of button every time pressed

Tags: swift, if-statement

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let softTime = 5
    let mediumTime = 7
    let hardTime = 12
    
    
    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
       // print(sender.currentTitle)
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle

/* I want print the of let if pressed first button or second ... */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

let softTime = 5
let mediumTime = 7
let hardTime = 12

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle

        //control flow
        if (hardness == "Soft") {
            print(softTime)
        }else if (hardness == "Medium") {
            print(mediumTime)
        }else if (hardness == "Hard") {
            print(hardTime)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Common decision

Answer (score 0):

The .currentTitle property is an optional and must be unwrapped.  Try this:

```
@IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
  if let buttonTitle = sender.title(for: .normal) {
    print(buttonTitle)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// thank you guys I fount the answer

```
switch hardness {
    case "Soft":
        print(5)
    case "Medium":
        print(7)
    case "Hard":
        print(12)
    default:
        print("Error")
    }
}
```